# When is TeX in "no mode"?

Tags: tex-core

TeX can be in 7 distinct modes:

1. Vertical mode: this is the mode in which TeX starts, and build pages.
2. Internal vertical mode: TeX is in this mode within `\vbox{...}`.
3. Horizontal mode: when constructing paragraphs.
4. Restricted horizontal mode: within an `\hbox{...}`.
5. Display math mode: `$$...$$` (and LaTeX's other display math environments).
6. Math mode: `$...$` for inline math.
7. No mode: only within `\write` commands?

The existence of the `no mode` mode can be ascertained by running

```
\tracingall
\immediate\write16{\iftrue\fi}
\end
```

(with the plain TeX format). The log contains

```
 \write->\iftrue \fi 
 {no mode: \iftrue: (level 1)}
 {true}
 {\fi: \iftrue (level 1)}

 {vertical mode: blank space  }
 {\end}
```

As you can see, TeX writes down the mode for the first command run in that mode. In this snippet, we can see `no mode` and `vertical mode`.

So far, I noted that neither `\message` nor `\special` change the mode to `no mode`. Only `\write` seems to do it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`no mode` in tex.web corresponds to the variable `mode`having the value `0`. This can be seen in the procedure `print_mode` (§211), i.e.,

```
else if m=0 then print("no")
```

Now the only place in TeX where this variable is set to zero is in §1371 which is the code that expands a `\write` statement.

So the answer to your question is: yes that is the only place.

Comment: Interestingly, `tex.web` states (about *\[16] The semantic nest*) that `The mode is temporarily set to zero while processing \.{\\write} texts in the |ship_out| routine.` It doesn't mention `\immediate\write`, in which the mode is also set to zero.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch well in the end you have to go by the code even though TeX is fairly well documented. You might earn $2.56 as docu bug fee one day if you report it but probably not be fore the next decade ;-). It is understandable that `\immediate` behaves like this too, but less so that `\special` doesn't.

Comment: It seems natural that `\special{\ifvmode...\else...\fi}` would let you access the mode in effect when the `\special` is triggered, since expansion happens immediately. On the other hand, `\write-1{\ifvmode...\fi}` gets expanded late, so there is no obvious notion of "current mode" (Can nodes migrate from hlist to vlist?). It would be most consistent if `\immediate\write` used the current mode, not "no mode". --- Are documentation fixes rewarded too? I thought my only hope for a Knuth cheque was `\batchmode\def\foo#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9#}{}\errorstopmode\show\foo`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch -- yes, documentation bugs are rewarded too.  if frank says this is worth reporting, please report it.  you can get the e-mail address for reports from [don knuth's web site](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/abcde.html).  the schedule he lists there says that he will next look at reports in 2013, so submit it soon, because it has to be vetted by a designated bug-checker before it gets sent on. if it passes this vetting process, knuth will answer you with a clear explanation, even if he doesn't accept it for a reward.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I will do that.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch thinking about this you are right one could even argue that this is  not just a documentation bug but a programming one and `\immediate`should leave the mode alone. But for very good reasons I'm certain there will be no change here. But mentioning correctly how the program behaves is something that could be considered a doc bug. And if it talks about shipout then it certainly doesn't cover the `\immediate` case.

Comment: @Bruno Just to verify, the behavior here is that even though with fewer than 9 arguments, the `#}` syntax is an error, with 9 it is accepted (and only in batch mode!) it is accepted?  How did you find that?

Comment: @RyanReich The reason batch mode helps is that it hides the error: try it without `\batchmode`.  I found that by looking at how TeX recovers from `\def\foo#################{}`: the ninth parameter ends up being delimited by `#`.  So then I figured I would try with `}`, and it worked.  Something similar happens (weird error recovery) if you `\read` a file containing `{%` to a variable: the variable becomes a macro expanding to a single open brace.

Comment: @RyanReich Ah, you need to set `\endlinechar=-1` to really get a single brace.

Comment: @Bruno: Ironic that the error recovery code contains an error.

Answer (score 7):

This question has been answered already, but this is relevant and interesting.

In [TUGboat, Volume 11 (1990), No. 2](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/contents11-2.html), Knuth gives a set of ["Exercises for *TeX: The Program*"](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb11-2/tb28knut.pdf), of which number 23 is

> 23. Find a short program that will cause the
>       *print_mode* subroutine to print '`no mode`'. (Do not
>       assume that the category codes or macros of plain
>       TeX have been preloaded.) Extra credit will be
>       given to the person who has the shortest program,
>       i.e., the fewest tokens, among all correct solutions
>       submitted.

Then the [followup article](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb11-4/tb30knut-exercises.pdf), which provides answers to the exercises, says

> 23. TeX is in 'no mode' only while processing
>       `\write` statements, and the mode is printed during
>       `\write` only when *tracing_commands* > 1 during
>       expand. We might think that `\catcode` operations
>       are necessary, so that the left and right braces
>       for `\write` exist; but it's possible to let TeX's
>       error-recovery mechanism supply them! Therefore
>       the shortest program that meets the requirements
>       is probably the following one based on an idea due
>       to Ronaldo Amá, who suggests putting
>
> ```
>     \batchmode\tracingcommands2
>     \immediate\write!\nomode
> ```
>
> into a file. (Seven tokens total.)

So let's try it. I'm using iniTeX just to show that there's no dependency on plain TeX (though it will work if plain TeX is loaded). Please pardon the horribly outdated TeX Live version; it's the simplest way for me to get iniTeX at this moment.

```
$ ed
a
\batchmode\tracingcommands2
\immediate\write!\nomode
.
wq nomode.tex
53
$ initex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (INITEX)
**\input nomode.tex
(./nomode.tex
$
```

Oh, right. Because of `\batchmode`, all of the important output is in the transcript file, which I will reproduce in its entirety.

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (INITEX)  5 JAN 2020 10:11
**\input nomode.tex
(./nomode.tex
{vertical mode: \immediate}
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   !
l.2 \immediate\write!
                     \nomode
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   !
l.2 \immediate\write!
                     \nomode
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

)
Runaway text?
!\nomode 
! File ended while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
<*> \input nomode.tex

I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

{no mode: undefined}
! Undefined control sequence.
<write> !\nomode 

...
<*> \input nomode.tex

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

!
! Emergency stop.
<*> \input nomode.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

No pages of output.
```

Comment: Very nice find, thanks!